# Group Count based on Specific Time Window for Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to be able to count the number of activities by a user over certain time of window (for example every 12 hours) for multiple users. For example, I have a table with dataset as follow:

| Timestamp | User |
| --- | --- |
| 08/11/2021 04:05:06 | A |
| 08/11/2021 04:15:06 | B |
| 08/11/2021 09:15:26 | A |
| 08/11/2021 11:04:06 | B |
| 08/11/2021 14:55:16 | A |
| 09/11/2021 04:12:11 | B |

and so on. I would like to be able to derive the data to be like this:

| Timestamp | User | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08/11/2021 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 | A | 2 |
| 08/11/2021 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 | B | 2 |
| 08/11/2021 12:00:00 - 23:59:59 | A | 1 |
| 08/11/2021 12:00:00 - 23:59:59 | B | 0 |
| 09/11/2021 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 | A | 0 |
| 09/11/2021 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 | B | 1 |

Is there a way to do this? I am still new in Scala and Spark so not too sure on how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look to https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/

Comment: Should the last row with User `B` have the count of `1` instead of `0` since there are `3` `B`s and one with a timestamp of `08/11/2021 04:15:06`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting your timestamp value to the respective `00:00:00 - 11:59:59` or `12:00:00 - 23:59:59` time period, you may easily perform a group by on the resulting data. Using the `HOUR` method to retrieve the hour of day, you may use this to determine which period to assign each row in. Moreover combining this with `CONCAT` to create the new time period and `to_date` to convert your timestamp to a date you may create this time period value.

You may try the following approaches:

##### Using scala api

```
outputDf = 
    df.withColumn(
        "TimePeriod",
        concat(
            to_date("Timestamp"),
            when(
                hour("Timestamp")<12," 00:00:00 - 11:59:59"
            ).otherwise(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")
        )
    )
    .groupBy(
        "TimePeriod",
        "User"
    )
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriod","Timestamp")

outputDf.show(truncate=false)
```

##### Using pyspark api

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "TimePeriod",
        F.concat(
            F.to_date("Timestamp"),
            F.when(
                F.hour("Timestamp")<12," 00:00:00 - 11:59:59"
            ).otherwise(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")
        )
    )
    .groupBy(
        "TimePeriod",
        "User"
    )
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriod","Timestamp")
)
output_df.show(truncate=False)
```

##### Using spark sql

1. Ensure your dataframe is available

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df2")
```

2. Run the following sql on the spark session

```
outputDf = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

SQL:

```sql
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            to_date(Timestamp),
            CASE
                WHEN HOUR(Timestamp) < 12 THEN ' 00:00:00 - 11:59:59'
                ELSE ' 12:00:00 - 23:59:59'
            END
        ) as Timestamp,
        User,
        COUNT(1) as COUNT
    FROM
        input_df2
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

##### Output

```
+------------------------------+----+-----+
|Timestamp                     |User|COUNT|
+------------------------------+----+-----+
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |2    |
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|A   |2    |
|2021-11-09 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |1    |
|2021-11-08 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|A   |1    |
+------------------------------+----+-----+
```

***NB:** Your timestamp column should be of the timestamp data type which can be verified using `df.printSchema()`. If your timestamp column is a string type you may use `to_timestamp` to convert it to a timestamp type eg `to_timestamp(Timestamp,"dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s")`*

### Edit 1 : Question Changed By Op

The following update will provide the count of users on all possible time periods. A cross-join of all possible user-time-periods with the count of actual users for each time period was used below.

##### Using scala api

```scala
timeperiods = 
    df.select(to_date("Timestamp").alias("TimestampDate"))
      .distinct()
      .withColumn("TimePeriodLower",concat("TimestampDate",lit(" 00:00:00 - 11:59:59")))
      .withColumn("TimePeriodUpper",concat("TimestampDate",lit(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")));


timeperiods = 
    timeperiods.select("TimePeriodLower")
               .union(
                   timeperiods.select("TimePeriodUpper")
               )
               .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriodLower","TimePeriod")
               .crossJoin(
                   df.select("User").distinct()
               );


outputDf = 
    df.withColumn(
        "TimePeriod",
        concat(
            to_date("Timestamp"),
            when(
                hour("Timestamp")<12," 00:00:00 - 11:59:59"
            ).otherwise(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")
        )
    )
    .groupBy(
        "TimePeriod",
        "User"
    )
    .count()
    .join(
        timeperiods,
        Seq("TimePeriod","User"),
        "right"
    )
    .withColumn("count",coalesce("count",lit(0)))
    .drop("Timestamp")
    .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriod","Timestamp");
```

##### Using pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

timeperiods = (
    df.select(F.to_date("Timestamp").alias("TimestampDate"))
      .distinct()
      .withColumn("TimePeriodLower",F.concat("TimestampDate",F.lit(" 00:00:00 - 11:59:59")))
      .withColumn("TimePeriodUpper",F.concat("TimestampDate",F.lit(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")))
)

timeperiods = (
    timeperiods.select("TimePeriodLower")
               .union(
                   timeperiods.select("TimePeriodUpper")
               )
               .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriodLower","TimePeriod")
               .crossJoin(
                   df.select("User").distinct()
               )
)

outputDf = (
    df.withColumn(
        "TimePeriod",
        F.concat(
            F.to_date("Timestamp"),
            F.when(
                F.hour("Timestamp")<12," 00:00:00 - 11:59:59"
            ).otherwise(" 12:00:00 - 23:59:59")
        )
    )
    .groupBy(
        "TimePeriod",
        "User"
    )
    .count()
    .join(
        timeperiods,
        ["TimePeriod","User"],
        "right"
    )
    .withColumn("count",F.coalesce("count",F.lit(0)))
    .drop("Timestamp")
    .withColumnRenamed("TimePeriod","Timestamp")
    
)
```

##### Using spark sql

1. Ensure your dataframe is available

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df2")
```

2. Run the following sql on the spark session

```
outputDf = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

SQL:

```sql
WITH unique_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        User 
    FROM 
        input_df2
),
unique_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        to_date(Timestamp) as TimestampDate 
    FROM 
        input_df2
),
timeperiods as (
    SELECT CONCAT(TimestampDate,' 00:00:00 - 11:59:59') as TimePeriod FROM unique_dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(TimestampDate,' 12:00:00 - 23:59:59') as TimePeriod FROM unique_dates
),
timeperiod_users as (
    SELECT * FROM timeperiods CROSS JOIN unique_users
),
timeperiod_user_counts as (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            to_date(Timestamp),
            CASE
                WHEN HOUR(Timestamp) < 12 THEN ' 00:00:00 - 11:59:59'
                ELSE ' 12:00:00 - 23:59:59'
            END
        ) as Timeperiod,
        User,
        COUNT(1) as COUNT
    FROM
        input_df2
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT
    tu.TimePeriod as Timestamp,
    tu.User,
    COALESCE(tuc.COUNT,0) as COUNT
FROM
    timeperiod_user_counts tuc
RIGHT JOIN
    timeperiod_users tu ON tu.TimePeriod = tuc.TimePeriod AND
                           tu.User = tuc.User
```

##### Outputs

```
outputDf.orderBy("Timestamp","User").show()
```

```
+------------------------------+----+-----+
|Timestamp                     |User|count|
+------------------------------+----+-----+
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|A   |2    |
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |2    |
|2021-11-08 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|A   |1    |
|2021-11-08 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|B   |0    |
|2021-11-09 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|A   |0    |
|2021-11-09 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |1    |
|2021-11-09 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|A   |0    |
|2021-11-09 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|B   |0    |
+------------------------------+----+-----+
```

```
timeperiods.show()
```

```
+------------------------------+----+
|TimePeriod                    |User|
+------------------------------+----+
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |
|2021-11-08 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|A   |
|2021-11-09 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|B   |
|2021-11-09 00:00:00 - 11:59:59|A   |
|2021-11-08 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|B   |
|2021-11-08 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|A   |
|2021-11-09 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|B   |
|2021-11-09 12:00:00 - 23:59:59|A   |
+------------------------------+----+
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't output `0` if there is/are **no logs (activities)** which could be important! I assume that OP needs this count to understand the behaviour of user logs/events. e.g. User `B` had no logs between 12:00-24:00 on both available dates/Timestamp!

Comment: @Mario The Op had changed the question. I have updated the answer with an edit that responds to the new question.

Answer (score 1):

**PySpark:**

This time resolution count can be achieved by using `hour` from `Timestamp` and `groupBy` on `date` & `User` within the Spark dataframe as follows:

```py
#Aggeragate records numbers for specific features (User) for certain time-resolution PerDay(24hrs), HalfDay(2x12hrs)
df = new_df.groupBy("User", "date").agg(
    F.sum(F.hour("Timestamp").between(0, 24).cast("int")).alias("NoLogPerDay"),
    F.sum(F.hour("Timestamp").between(0, 11).cast("int")).alias("NoLogPer-1st-12-hrs"),
    F.sum(F.hour("Timestamp").between(12, 23).cast("int")).alias("NoLogPer-2nd-12-hrs"),

).sort('date')

df.show(truncate = False)
```

Please see the results as your expected frame:

```
|timestamp          |UserName|
+-------------------+--------+
|2021-08-11 04:05:06|A       |
|2021-08-11 04:15:06|B       |
|2021-08-11 09:15:26|A       |
|2021-08-11 11:04:06|B       |
|2021-08-11 14:55:16|A       |
|2021-09-11 04:12:11|B       |
+-------------------+--------+

+-------------------+----------+--------+
|timestamp          |date      |UserName|
+-------------------+----------+--------+
|2021-08-11 04:05:06|2021-08-11|A       |
|2021-08-11 04:15:06|2021-08-11|B       |
|2021-08-11 09:15:26|2021-08-11|A       |
|2021-08-11 11:04:06|2021-08-11|B       |
|2021-08-11 14:55:16|2021-08-11|A       |
|2021-09-11 04:12:11|2021-09-11|B       |
+-------------------+----------+--------+

+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|UserName|date      |NoLogPerDay|NoLogPer-1st-12-hrs|NoLogPer-2nd-12-hrs|
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|A       |2021-08-11|3          |2                  |1                  |
|B       |2021-08-11|2          |2                  |0                  |
|B       |2021-09-11|1          |1                  |0                  |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```